# starting an app with NFC intent not showing on recent

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I have a simple application that will read a NFC tag, I am able to run it and it works fine. The problem is that if the app is automatically launched from the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent filter it will not be present on the recent apps, if instead I launch it from myself I am able to see it on the recents list.

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:excludeFromRecents="false"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:label="@string/app_name" android:excludeFromRecents="false" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

any idea why this problem is happening? I'm using

```
android:excludeFromRecents="false"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

that I've read could be the problems, but no solution yet.